# Verifying equality $ (\vec a \times \vec b)^2 = \left| \vec a \times \vec b \right| ^2 $

Tags: linear-algebra, vector, vector-calculus, education

I'm trying to verify the equality $ (\vec a \times \vec b)^2 = \left| \vec a \times \vec b \right| ^2 $ in *Mathematica*. How can I do it?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another explicit way

```
veca = {a1, a2, a3};
vecb = {b1, b2, b3};

Cross[veca, vecb].Cross[veca, vecb] - Norm[Cross[veca, vecb]]^2 // Simplify[#, veca~Join~vecb \[Element] Reals] &
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$Assumptions = (a | b) \[Element] Vectors[3]
Cross[a, b].Cross[a, b] // TensorExpand
(*-(a.b)^2 + a.a b.b*)
```